# use ajax success:function(data) on document ready jquery function

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-mobile

I am loading responsive calendar in document ready :

```
eventList=disp();    
        $(".responsive-calendar").responsiveCalendar({
                    events:eventList //json object data 
                });
        function disp(){   
              //getArr(); 
              //alert(data1); //not working
              stb = '{';
              edb = '}';
              dt = ["2015-09-13","2015-10-22","2015-10-02"]; // dynamically to be created from ajax data
              ct = [2,5,6];     // dynamically to be created from ajax data
              ev = dt.length;
              var ddt = stb;
              for(var i=0; i<ev;i++){
                ddt += '"' + dt[i] + '":{"number":'+ct[i]+'},';
              }
              mString = ddt.substring(0,ddt.length-1) 
              ddt = mString+edb;
              return JSON.parse(ddt);
          }
        function getArr() {
          $.ajax({
            url:"../JLRFile.php",  
            success:function(data) {
              data1 = data; 
            }
          });
        }
```

Here in disp() I need dt and ct to load from ajax data function, can any one provide proper solution, I called ajax function in disp() but its not working.
Please provide proper solution

Comment: you should read this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function

Comment: I'm sorry but i didn't get it.. How the way I use it?

Comment: just call `disp` inside the success callback with proper parameters .

Comment: Try making the url variable absolute. You didn't call disp anywhere in your code

Comment: You will get data when you Ajax call Successfull.Please do what you want to perform on data After ajax Success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
eventList = getArr();
$(".responsive-calendar").responsiveCalendar({
    events: eventList //json object data 
});
function disp(data1) { 
    alert(data1); //getting now
    stb = '{';
    edb = '}';
    dt = ["2015-09-13", "2015-10-22", "2015-10-02"]; // dynamically to be created from ajax data
    ct = [2, 5, 6];     // dynamically to be created from ajax data
    ev = dt.length;
    var ddt = stb;
    for (var i = 0; i < ev; i++) {
        ddt += '"' + dt[i] + '":{"number":' + ct[i] + '},';
    }
    mString = ddt.substring(0, ddt.length - 1)
    ddt = mString + edb;
    return JSON.parse(ddt);
}
function getArr() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "../JLRFile.php",
        success: function (data) {
            data1 = data;
            disp(data1);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks parth.. m getting the data.. but I am not able to manipulate on data as i need it to get two diff array from data in dt and ct and with respect to that dt and ct i need to form a a json object to pass to events in responsive calendar

Comment: If I write return data1.length; in disp() it is returning undefined in eventList

Comment: Please Verify that first we it had to call eventList = getArr();